# Angular drag-and-drop form builder

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, formbuilder

We have a website in angularjs can anyone suggest a drag-and-drop form builder library so users will be able to create some simple forms from ui?

Comment: Try this : http://kelp404.github.io/angular-form-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Ng-formbuider library provides form building capabilities to an angular js appication.
It will be helpful for you. We are also working on this.

```
<http://codepen.io/travist/full/xVyMjo/>
```